# Replacing a value in an column based on another Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to replace a value in a column based on another existing column.

The 2 columns look like this

```
id_30       DeviceInfoShort

Android     SAMSUNG
iOS         iOS
None        Windows
None        None
Mac         MacOS
Windows     Windows
None        None
```

id_30 columns have "None" which is not showing in the picture.
What I want is for all "None" values in id_30 columns, it will check if the value in DeviceInfoShort is "Windows", if yes, replace "None" in id_30 with "Windows", otherwise "Android"

Code below is what I have. It works fine but it took 10 mins to run. I think I can use map/apply here to make it faster...is there a more elegant way of doing this using pandas?

```py
%%time
for r in train_all_data.index:
    if train_all_data.loc[r, 'id_30'] == 'None':
        if train_all_data.loc[r, 'DeviceInfoShort'] == 'Windows':
            train_all_data.loc[r, 'id_30'] = 'Windows'
        else:
            train_all_data.loc[r, 'id_30'] = 'Android'
```

Comment: What do you mean by `if yes, replace "None" in id_30 with "Windows", otherwise "Android"`. If there is no None, it has some value. Also, please refrain yourself from posting an image. Copy paste the sample dataframe so that every can reproduce.

Comment: Did you by any chance swapped `id_30` and `DeviceInfoShort`? Only in the latter, there are `None`s.

Comment: `df['DeviceInfoShort'] = np.where((df['DeviceInfoShort'] == 'None'), df['id_30'], df['DeviceInfoShort'])`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've copy paste another set of the table. Both columns have "None" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pandas / Numpy `where`:

```py
df['id_30'] = df['id_30'].where(
    df['id_30'].notna(), 
    np.where(df['DeviceInfoShort'] == 'Windows', 'Windows', 'Android'))
```

Comment: The more-complete version of what I gave in my comment. But `notna()` won't pick up on `'None'` strings, will it? You need to test against equality to `'None'`

Comment: Indeed, if there are 'None' strings, `df['id_30'].notna()` could be replaced by `(df['id_30'].notna()) & (df['id_30'] != 'None')`

Comment: Thank you so much! this is what I wanted. only 64 ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = train_all_data[train_all_data['id_30'] == 'None']
train_all_data.loc[temp, 'id_30'] = 'Andorid'
temp1 = train_all_data[(train_all_data['id_30'] == 'None') & (train_all_data['DeviceInfoShort'] == 'Windows')]
train_all_data.loc[temp1, 'id_30'] = 'Windows'
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be faster:

```
df['id_30'] = df.apply(lambda x: "Windows" if x.id_30 == "None" and x.DeviceInfoShort == "Windows" else "Android")
```

From my experience using apply() is always faster than looping through

Comment: No it isn't. `apply` just uses a `for` loop.

Comment: It has to, you're calling a python function (the `lambda`) so that call cannot be pushed into C in the same way as a vectorized calculation. As soon as you call a python function, vectorization is off the table.